# Primeng p-multiSelect filter not work correct

Tags: angular, primeng

In html file:

```
<p-multiSelect [filter]="true" [options]="cities1 [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1"></p-multiSelect>
```

In component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.testMultiSelect();
}

testMultiSelect() {
    interval(3000).pipe().subscribe(() => {
     this.cities1 = [
      { label: 'New York', value: { id: 1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY' } },
      { label: 'Rome', value: { id: 2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM' } },
      { label: 'London', value: { id: 3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN' } },
      { label: 'Istanbul', value: { id: 4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST' } },
      { label: 'Paris', value: { id: 5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS' } }
    ];
  });
}
```

1. after p-multiSelect load data, I enter in input filter of
   p-multiSelect is 'new', result of p-multiSelect after filter is: 'New
   York'.
2. I await 3s, text in input filter is 'new' but result of p-multiSelect is: 
   'New York, Rome, London, Istanbul, Paris'
3. expect the output after 3s result of p-multiSelect is: 'New York' and text 
   in input filter is 'new'.
   [this is image for this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeeoa.png)

   please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interval you have set is reseting the filter for the multiselect. If you remove it it will filter just fine.

Do you need the interval?

Comment: Hi Samuel Sánchez Blümli, yes, I need the interval.

Comment: If you need the user to wait for three seconds before seeing the result, which I do not recomend, then use the inputs keypress event to filter the array yourself and change the items when the three seconds have gone by.